# background image not working in Chrome 25

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, background-image

[image: Background problem]

I tried to style a select. It is working more or less in all browsers except in IE and Chrome. The big question for me is why isn't it working in Chrome 25?

On the left side you can see how it should look like and on the right side how it looks like in Chrome.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="selectContainer">
    <select name="adults" class="select-style" size="1">
        <?php
            for ($i=1; $i<=99; $i++){
                echo '<option>' . $i . '</option>';
            }
        ?>
    </select>
</div>
<div class="selectDescription">
    <span class="annotation">Erwachsene</span>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.selectContainer {
    background-image: url('../img/select-style.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #006633;
    border-radius: 0px 0px 8px 8px; 
    -moz-border-radius: 0px 0px 8px 8px; 
    -webkit-border-radius: 0px 0px 8px 8px;
    width: 36px;
    overflow: hidden;
    float: left;
}

.select-style {
    width: 57px;
    height: 27px;
    border: none;
    background: none;
    padding-top: 5px;
    color: #95C11F;
}

.selectDescription {
    line-height: 27px;
    float: left;
    padding-left: 5px;
}
```

**Live example:**
http://bfb.bplaced.net/test/

Comment: It works for me in Chrome 25.0.1364.99.

Comment: In chrome 26 under my linux it does work well (maybe that's a bug in chrome that they solved in the version 26).

Comment: @Intelekshual: Here I have a `Chrome 25.0.1364.97 m` and it doesn't work. It also says that I have the latest update. Perhaps depending on the country?

Comment: Not working for me either. Strange because it is indeed a white BG. If you set the select element to have a opacity of .5, you can see the green bg behind it. Hmmm.

Comment: Working on `Chrome 22.0.1229.94`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `-webkit-appearance: none;` to the `.select-style` class and it works in chrome ..

Seems like webkit is a little stricter with styling the `<select>` element ..

---

Also don't forget to add this if you don't want Chrome/Firefox's default orange border on focus:

```
:focus { outline-style: none; }
::-moz-focus-inner { border-style: none; }
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6vV8E/)